# Is there a way to set missing values for all items at once in a data.set using memisc in R?

Tags: r

Memisc is an R package that allows for convenient handling of survey data by using a data type called "data.set" which is a list of "items," which are analogous to factors/variables in a dataframe.

I have a data.set where `"-99"` represents missing responses (refused) and `NA` represents not applicable responses. I want to set `missing.values(data$item) = c(-99)` for all items. Is there a way to do that easily, rather than copy-paste-editing for each of my 170 items?

Ideally without a for-loop, but I can't figure out how to do it with a for-loop, either so if that's possible, it would be helpful to know how.

Edit: I couldn't figure out how to use dput() to give you reproducible data, because pasting the output from dput() threw errors. In trying to make a model adapted from the memisc documentation, I discovered a function called foreach() that seems to do what I want.  Only it requires you to list out the column names by hand.  Like this example simplified from the documentation:

```
ds <- data.set(
a = c(1,2,3,2,3,8,9),
b = c(2,8,3,2,1,8,9),
c = c(1,3,2,1,2,8,8)
)

ds <- within(ds,{
    foreach(x=c(a,b,c),{ # Lazy data documentation:
    labels(x) <- c( # a,b,c get value labels in one statement
        one = 1,
        two = 2,
        three = 3,
        "don't know" = 8,
        "refused to answer" = 9)
    missing.values(x) <- c(8,9)
    })
})
```

Is there a way to use foreach() or for() that just specifies "all the items" even if you don't know how many there are?  Even though ds is a list (data.sets are a kind of list), this doesn't work:

```
ds <- within(ds, {
    foreach(x=ds, missing.values(x) <- c(3))
    }
missing.values(ds$a)  #still 8 and 9, not 3
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Thanks, Quinten!  I tried, and the exercise was very helpful for me!